# Having problems reading the dimensions of matrix from text files, using row and col and add them together

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I'm using C++ to read from two .txt files. The first number in the .txt file represents the rows. The second number represents the columns. Then the remaining numbers is for the matrix. I'm getting an error while trying to scan the dimensions. I tried declaring two ints. I also tried using constants and I still get errors.

This is the requirements to help understand what I'm trying to do.
[Matrix Addition[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUXq2.jpg)

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    /**
    * Integer n and m are declared to store the row and column
    * respectively
    */
    
    
    const int n = 8;
    const int m = 8;
    int arr[n][m];


    //int n, m;

    /**
    * below we create object of file named myFile for file matrix.txt
    */
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(filename.c_str());

    /**
    * scanning dimensions of first matrix
    */
    myfile >> n >> m;

    /**
    * Creating double type 2d array named matrix1
    */
    double matrix1[n][m];
    /**
    * In following nested for loop we scan data into the array matrix1
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            myfile >> matrix1[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "MATRIX 1" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << right << setw(5) << matrix1[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    /***
    * Data scanning for matrix 2
    */
    /**
    * Integer p and q are declared to store the row and column
    * respectively of matrix2
    */
    const int p = 8;
    const int q = 8;
    int arr2 [p][q];
    //int p, q;
    /**
    * scanning dimensions of first matrix
    */
    myfile >> p >> q;

    /**
    * Creating double type 2d array named matrix2
    */
    double matrix2[p][q];
    /**
    * In following nested for loop we scan data into the array matrix2
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
            myfile >> matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "MATRIX 2" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
            cout << right << setw(5) << matrix2[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    /**
    * Check if matrix1 and matrix2 can be added
    */
    if (n == p && m == q) {
        double matrix3[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
                matrix3[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "ADDITION of MATRIX 1 AND MATRIX 2" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
                cout << right << setw(5) << matrix3[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Both matrix cannot be added!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const int n = 8;
const int m = 8;
```

These two `int`s are ***constant***. That means that their value cannot be changed. They are etched in stone. They will forever contain 8, both. That's what `const` means in C++.

```
myfile >> n >> m;
```

This attempts to read two integer value from `myfile` into `n` and `m`. However, that's impossible, because we've just determined that these two variables are constant. They cannot be changed. Their values cannot be read from a file, or set in any other way.

And you cannot simply remove the `const` keyword either, because:

```
int arr[n][m];
```

In C++ the sizes of all arrays are fixed and they must be specified as a constant value at ***compile time***. I surmise that you initially declared `n` and `m` to be ordinary `int`s, your compiler complained that you can't do this unless they are constant, you then changed them to `const int`s, then the compiler complained that they are not initialized, then you tried initializing them from 8, and now you cannot figure out the reason for the current compilation error.

C allows you to declare an array whose size comes from a non-constant expression at a run time, but this is not valid in C++ (although some compilers will accept this as a non-standard C++ extension).

Your C++ programming assignment requires you to do one of two things: either allocate the matrix dynamically, or use `std::vector`s. Either of these approaches effectively implement arrays whose size is established at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[n][m];
```

is not being used anywhere in the code. So that can be removed.
const declarations for m, n can be replaced by the code that has been commented out

```
int m, n;
```

With these changes there shouldn't be a problem reading the dimensions of the matrix from the file. But as Sam pointed out you need to dynamically allocate the 2D arrays using malloc/new or use a std::vectorstd::vector>. You can also use boost's Matrix class - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm